# how to divide the dynamic array values so maintain 100% width result for css

Tags: javascript

Here is the array `[2, 44, 7, 38]`. It's the string length of my table cells, so the table width is 100%. Now table will have 4 columns as the same as the length of the array. Now I want to convert this array into width percentage as more big values will get more place in the table.
I need the js method to convert an array that has dynamic length and inside it, dynamic values but it should give % to more which value is big.[image: Explain by image]

Comment: Unless you're using a monospace font, the string char length is not going to be proportional to its rendered length.

Comment: @Mian person: Why do you need to calculate the column widths? Html tables with some css can provide pretty decent auto-widths (retaining a total table width of 100%). See this [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/yLjPyzj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the aim is to produce an array of widths in units appropriate to a UI (like px) that are proportional to the input string lengths.

The way to do this is to normalize the string lengths -- divide each by the sum of the lengths -- then apply those proportions to the new units.

```js
const array = [2, 44, 7, 38];
const sum = array.reduce((acc, i) => acc+i, 0);
const normalized = array.map(i => i/sum);

// applied to, say, 600 px
const totalWidth = 600;
const widths = normalized.map(n => n*totalWidth);
console.log(widths)
```

In functional form:

```
// answer an array of values proportional to lengths summing to totalWidth
function widthsFromLengths(lengths, totalWidth) {
  const sum = lengths.reduce((acc, i) => acc+i, 0);
  const normalized = lengths.map(i => i/sum);
  return normalized.map(n => n*totalWidth);
}
```

Note that if the goal is to proportionally fit text rendered in a variable width font, the input strings can/should first be converted to widths via an idea like the one given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21015393/294949).

Answer (score 0):

Let us take a look at this snippet

```js
function calculateWidth(arr, container) {
  let nodes = container.children;
  let sum = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }, 0);
  if (nodes.length > arr.length) {
    alert("Not enough elements in the array");
    return;
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      nodes[i].style.width = 100 * arr[i] / sum + "%";
    }
  }
}

const arr = [2, 44, 7, 38];
let container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
calculateWidth(arr, container);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
}

.container * {
  height: 100%;
  outline: 2px ridge royalblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>he</p>
  <p>i love your help please help kindly</p>
  <p>okokokokokokok</p>
  <p>i love your help please help kindly</p>
</div>
```

The magic happens in the function `calculateWidth`.

It will receive an array as `arr` and a node element that elements inside it would be width-ifying :) as "container".

The `nodes` variable would have the elements, that are the children of `arr. &` sum` would be, well, *sum* of the numbers in the arr.

if the size of the `arr` is less than nodes', then the operation would be cancelled otherwise, in a for loop, the width of the elements in `nodes` would be calculated and assigned.